# Set camera in Google Maps 3D view using JavaScript

Tags: google-maps, 3d, maps

I have recorded flight track data (lat, lon, altitude, angle, speed...) and want to simulate a cockpit view of the recorded flight.

Is there a JavaScript API to do this in 3D Google Maps (set and move camera view in Google Maps 3D)?

I am new to Google Maps API and cannot find documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it using Javascript API. But closest thing for this is by using [Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling). As of now only [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#introduction) and [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view.html#property-documentation)
 can do it.

Answer (score -1):

I found the very cool framework [cesiumjs](https://www.cesium.com/)

which provides excatly what i was searching for.

Set camera with heading, roll, pitch and altitude.